# Setting unique keywords for each person via discord bot

Tags: python, python-3.6, discord.py

I am currently attempting to make a bot that allows members to set specific keywords that the bot then checks for in the server (over a period of time). If the bot detects that keyword in a message (via another bot/webhook only) it alerts the user who set that keyword.

Basically what I wish to do is something like this scenario:

Member 1 --->

!setkeyword new link

(bot then sets the keywords for member 1 specifically as "new link")

!listkeywords

(bot returns the word/phrase "new link")

---

Member 2 --->

!setkeyword new shoe

(bot then sets the keywords for member 1 specifically as "new shoe")

!listkeywords

(bot returns the word/phrase "new shoe")

The best that I came to was using a dictionary and a list. The key to the dictionary was the user id of the member who sets the keyword and the list contains the keyword.

Variation 1:
    dictt = {}

```
@bot.command()
async def add(ctx,keyword):
    listy = []
    listy.append(keyword)
    dictt[ctx.author.id] = listy
```

Variation 2:

```
 dictt = {}
 listy = []
 @bot.command()
 async def add(ctx,keyword):

    listy.append(keyword)
    dictt[ctx.author.id] = listy
```

Variation 1: This resulted in a new list being made every time a user messaged the bot. Meaning for each unique user only one keyword was in the list. So if a user tried to add multiple keywords only the most recent one was added to the list

Variation 2: This resulted in keywords from unique users being added to the same list, meaning each user could add multiple keywords but they weren't unique for each user.

How can I achieve each unique user having their own unique list and still being able to add multiple keywords to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a global `dict` and check if the user's id exists before appending, if not create a new list with the new word.

```py
memory = {}

def add(id, word):
    if id in memory.keys():
        memory[id].append(word)
    else:
        memory[id] = [word]
```

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be a save file. Setting a variable would be destroyed at the shutdown or restart or crash...

```
filepath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.optionxform = str
try:
    config.read(f'{filepath}/data/keywords.cfg')
    user1 = config['User1'] #This might be an Idea if you have every user stored in vars
except Exception as error:
    print(f" -- ERROR : File not detected.\n{error}")
quit()

#Or use it like this
@bot.command()
async def add(ctx,keyword):
    keywordlist = config.items(ctx.message.user.id, raw=True)
    keywordlist.append(keyword)
    config[ctx.message.user.id] = dict(keywordlist)

@bot.command()
async def list(ctx):
    keywordlist = config[ctx.message.user.id]
    await ctx.send(keywordlist)
```

The file would look like that :

> [123456789]
>   FirstKeyword
>   AnotherKeyWord
>
> [123789456]
>   Wow
>   Such
>   Code ...

Comment: I thought about doing this as well, but I expect hundreds of users to use this bot and I wouldn't like that many files

Comment: It would be a single file with every user stored inside.